# OS development - converting logical block format to Cylinder-Head-Sector

Tags: bootloader, osdev, floppy

I am referring BrokenThorn's OS development tutorial, and currently reading the part on developing a complete first stage bootloader that loads the second stage - [Bootloaders 4](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev6.html).

In the part of converting Logical Block Address (LBA) to Cylinder-Head-Sector (CHS) format, this is the code that is used -

```
LBACHS:
      xor     dx, dx                              ; prepare dx:ax for operation
      div     WORD [bpbSectorsPerTrack]           ; divide by sectors per track
      inc     dl                                  ; add 1 (obsolute sector formula)
      mov     BYTE [absoluteSector], dl
      xor     dx, dx                              ; prepare dx:ax for operation
      div     WORD [bpbHeadsPerCylinder]          ; mod by number of heads (Absolue head formula)
      mov     BYTE [absoluteHead], dl             ; everything else was already done from the first formula

      mov     BYTE [absoluteTrack], al            ; not much else to do :)
      ret
```

I am not able to understand the logic behind this conversion. I tried using a few sample values to walk through it and see how it works, but that got me even more confused. Can someone explain how this conversion works and the logic used ?

Comment: The formula for conversion **is provided in the article**. This question proves you didn't want to read, just copy code and hope to understand it by reading just it. You will fail miserably with this attitude. Also, regardless of what the tutorial does, ditch the floppy - you won't find any serious hardware still booting off it, and floppy BIOS interrupts have *many* problems, compared to just using "extended read" interrupt.

Comment: I know that the formula is given in the article and I have read it. I have only not copied it here. As I already mentioned, I tried running this through with a few numeric samples, but could not understand. I do not ask questions just as I encounter them without first trying myself, and that is what I have written in my question. As I said, I know the formulas - I only could not understand the logic behind them. And they are not explained very well in the article either.

Comment: The previous article on Brokenthorn explains **exactly** how it works. Try reading more closely next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that your LBA value is being stored in `AX` as you are performing division on some value.

As some pre-information for you, the `absoluteSector` is the CHS sector number, `absoluteHead` is the CHS head number, and `absoluteTrack` is the CHS cylinder number. Cylinders and tracks are the exact same thing, just a different name.

Also, the `DIV` operation for your code in 16-bit will take whatever is in the `DX:AX` register combination and divide it by some value. The remainder of the division will be in the `DX` register while the actual result will be in the `AX` register.

Next, the `*X` registers are 16-bit registers, where `*` is one of `ABCD`. They are made up of a low and high component, both referred to as `*H` and `*L` for high and low, respectively. For example, the `DX` register has `DH` for the upper 8 bits and `DL` for the lower 8 bits.

Finally, as the `BYTE` and `WORD` modifiers simply state the size of the data that will be used/transferred.

The first value you must extract is the sector number, which is obtained by diving the LBA value by the number of sectors per track. The `DL` register will then contain the sector number minus one. This is because counting sectors starts at 1, which is different than most values, which start at zero. To fix this, we add one to the `DL` register get the correct sector value. This value is stored in memory at `absoluteSector`.

The next value you must extract is the head number, which is obtained by dividing the result of the last `DIV` operation by the number of heads per cylinder. The `DL` register will then contain the head number, which we store at `absoluteHead`.

Finally, we get the track number. With the last division we already obtained the value, which is in the `AL` register. We then store this value at `absoluteTrack`.

Hope this cleared things up a little bit.

-Adrian

Comment: Thanks for this very well detailed answer. Its cleared up things a lot.
Just one question - what if I dont use logical block addressing and use the sector numbering from 1 ? How will that affect calculations ?

Comment: Each sector on the disk is on a specific head and track. The LBA value is simply the combination of these values so that you can access the sector linearly. As an example, in C you can have multidimensional arrays, such as `int i = data[c][h][s]`, where `data` is an array and c, h, and s are your CHS values. However, you can also access this linearly using `int i = *data[c * hpc * spt + h * spt + s]`, where hpc is heads per cylinder and spt is sectors per track. So, all in all, the process you are doing is basically just turning a linear index into a multidimensional array.